# How to create 2 different line item group and putting it together?

Tags: javascript, zapier

Does anybody know how to put a line item group within a line item?

Here is the sample of the code that I need to duplicate in Code mode in Zapier:

```
items: [
      {
        item_number: 2,
        item_name: 'Delivery1',
        quantity: 1,
        unit_of_measure: 'pieces',
        unit_price: 100,
        net_price: 100,
        tax_breakdown: [{regime: 'VAT', rate: 27, amount: 27}]
      }
    ]
```

In Developer Zapier / Input Designer there is a way to put a line item group (https://platform.zapier.com/docs/input-designer#how-to-add-a-line-item-group).

[image: Code Mode in Developer Zapier]

Comment: What is a line item group? Can you be more explicit in what you're trying to achieve and what you've tried

Comment: do you want all elements which contain item in their name to be in an array?

Comment: I am using code mode in developer zapier. In the code, "tax breakdown" is an array within an array. trying to do this in Developer Zapier.

Answer (score 0):

Likely related to [this](https://community.zapier.com/developer-discussion-13/how-to-input-multiple-items-in-a-nested-children-field-though-cli-while-setting-up-action-7471) or maybe it is as simple as using `JSON.stringify()` & `JSON.parse()`.

```
'items': [
      {
        'item_number': 2,
        'item_name': 'Delivery1',
        'quantity': 1,
        'unit_of_measure': 'pieces',
        'unit_price': 100,
        'net_price': 100,
        'tax_breakdown': JSON.stringify([{'regime': 'VAT', 'rate': 27, 'amount': 27}])
      }
    ]
```

Then parse it afterwards and give it a 'line item group name' at that point...